# Tutorial for PHP Amazon Simple Storage Service

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I'm about to integrate Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3) with a php web application that must maintain a lot of office documents and photoshop files.

Can anyone point me to a brief tutorial on how to do this?  There's "too much" documentation on the Amazon website for me to wade through.  I learn best by studying and tinkering with code that actually works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Zend, the S3 section has a great tutorial.

1. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.s3.html

If not, but don't want to roll your own code, try this:

http://undesigned.org.za/2007/10/22/amazon-s3-php-class

The basics are pretty ... basic:

```
$s3 = new S3('accessKey', 'secretKey');
$s3->putBucket('bucket', S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
$s3->putObjectFile('file.doc', 'bucket', 'docs/file.doc', S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
$s3->deleteObject('bucket', 'docs/file.doc');
```

Or this:

https://github.com/tpyo/amazon-s3-php-class

Which is a great library - I've used it. I prefer it to Zend S3.

Comment: Is this still valid? The PHP SDk docs dont seem to list a putObjectFile() method.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the official [SDK for php](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) from Amazon.

Start with the [Getting Started Guide](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/4261?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1), and then consult the [full library docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/) as needed.

If you are new to S3, the general [getting started guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/gsg/) should be useful in giving a general overview of how the service works.

Answer (score 1):

[This very nice tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-use-amazon-s3-php-to-dynamically-store-and-manage-files-with-ease/) comes with an added bonus; it links to an already-written library, so you won't have to write all the code yourself.